# Does java support multiple dispatch? If not how is the below code working?

Tags: java, polymorphism, multiple-dispatch

Does java support multiple dispatch? If not how is the below code working?

**Account.java**

```
public interface Account 
{
    public void calculateInterest();
}
```

**SavingsAccount.java**

```
public class SavingsAccount implements Account
{

}
```

**LoanAccount.java**

```
public class LoanAccount implements Account
{

}
```

**InterestCalculation.java**

```
public class InterestCalculation 
{
    public void getInterestRate(Account objAccount)
    {
        System.out.println("Interest Rate Calculation for Accounts");
    }

    public void getInterestRate(LoanAccount loanAccount)
    {
        System.out.println("Interest rate for Loan Account is 11.5%");
    }

    public void getInterestRate(SavingsAccount savingAccount)
    {
        System.out.println("Interest rate for Savings Account is 6.5%");
    }
}
```

**CalculateInterest.java**

```
public class CalculateInterest 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         InterestCalculation objIntCal = new InterestCalculation();
         objIntCal.getInterestRate(new LoanAccount());
         objIntCal.getInterestRate(new SavingsAccount());        
     }
}
```

**Output**

```
Interest rate for Loan Account is 11.5%
Interest rate for Savings Account is 6.5%
```

Comment: This is just how method overloading works. Your actual method parameters are specific subtypes, not merely `Account`.

Comment: You are telling method overloading and multiple dispatch are same?

Comment: new LoanAccount() and new SavingsAccount() are created at RunTime, Then how comes it is overloading?

Comment: try passing a variable of type `Account` , (assuming later at run time you will instansiate it with concrete object reference). In this case your method corresponding to Account as parameter will be invoked. It is simple method overloading you are having. When compiler sees same method name being invoked then it sees what is the argument you are passing in it and then it decides which method has matching parameters for those arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First some terminology

> [**Overloading**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) is the ability to create multiple methods of the
> same name with different implementations.

In Java, this is performed based on the compile-time type of the arguments, : the method with the [matching signature](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-in-java/) is used, independently of the argument's value.

> [**Overriding**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding)  allows a subclass or child class to provide a
> specific implementation of a method that is already provided by one of
> its superclasses or parent classes.

In Java, this is performed by determining the method to be called depending on the run-time (dynamic) type of the object referred to.  This is Java's way to implement [single dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch#Single_and_multiple_dispatch) and it is [not be confused with overloading](https://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-vs-method-overriding-in-java).

> [**Multiple dispatch**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) means that a function or method can be
> dynamically dispatched based on the run-time (dynamic) type or, in the
> more general case some other attribute, **of more than one of its
> arguments**.

#### Does Java support multiple dispatch ?

In Java, there's no direct support for multiple dispatch.

However you can [emulate multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#Java) by using several layers of single dispatch combined with overloading.

#### How is this code working ?

Note that this code to work first requires that you provide an implementation of `calculateInterest()` for `LoanAccount` and `SavingAccount`, even if it will not be used in the rest of your POC.

In your class `InterestCalculation` , you have three distinct overloads of the method `getInterestRate()`. They each have a distinct signature (e.g. argument type). So main() will invoke the right method depending on the declared type of the argument (which is deduced from the constructor).

You could optimize your use of single dispatch and make `InterestCalculation` much more general (e.g. you could then add many more implementations of `Account` without having to change it) :

```
public interface Account 
{
    public void calculateInterest();
    public double getInterest(); 
    public String getType(); 
}
...
public class InterestCalculation 
{
    public void getInterestRate(Account objAccount)
    {
        System.out.print ("Interest Rate for "+objAccount.getType()+" is ");
        System.out.print (objAccount.getInterest());
        System.out.println (" %");
    }
}
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/f0ANPY)