# Confused about single-dispatch in Java vs multiple dispatch

Tags: java, dispatch, multiple-dispatch, single-dispatch

I’ve read [a good post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960454/does-java-support-multiple-dispatch-if-not-how-is-the-below-code-working)

Just still a little confused about the concept of multiple dispatch (not in Java) vs single dispatch (in Java).

Let’s use this example:

```
class A { 
    m(A a) {
       System.out.println(“In A: “ + a.getClass());
    }
}
class B extends A {
    m(A a) {
       System.out.println(“In B.m(A): “ + a.getClass());
    }
    m(B a) {
       System.out.println(“In B.m(B): “ + a.getClass());
    }
}

A a = new A();
A b = new B();
B c = new B();

a.m(a);   // Java will call A.m(A); double-dispatch would call A.m(A)
b.m(b);   // Java will call B.m(A); double-dispatch would call B.m(B)
b.m(c);   // Java will call B.m(B); double-dispatch would call B.m(B)
```

•  Is it correct that multiple-dispatch looks at:

1. the dynamic types of the object that’s calling the method  (so, same as Java single-dispatch does)
2. the dynamic types of the arguments being passed to the method (so, apparently not the same as Java’s single-dispatch)

•  And so the difference between single-dispatch and multiple-dispatch is therefore #2 above, where single-dispatch uses the static types of the arguments instead of their dynamic types?

Thanks kindly for any insight

Comment: From my reading of the post you linked and the wikipedia article it links, the answer is #2.

Comment: It's one of those things that you don't really notice the usefulness of until you've used it. If all you've seen is single dispatch, it's hard to imagine having multiple dispatch. Try out Common Lisp or something with multidispatch if you're really interested in drawing the comparisons.